# getting SQL Error: ORA-01849: hour must be between 1 and 12

Tags: sql, oracle11g

To one table i have to update date for column DT_MODIFIED   TIMESTAMP(6) and while runing the script, iam getting below error.

```
update table1 set dt_modified=to_char('01Feb2016 20:04:08.000') where dt_stamp='XXXXX' and xcolumn=’YYYY’;

Error starting at line 6 in command:
update table1 set dt_modified=to_char('01Feb2016 20:04:08.000') where dt_stamp='XXXXX' and xcolumn=’YYYY’;
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01849: hour must be between 1 and 12
01849. 00000 -  "hour must be between 1 and 12"
```

Please guide me on this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were several problems with your original approach.  First, since you are trying to store a date into the `DT_MODIFIED` column, you should be using `TO_DATE` or `TO_TIMESTAMP`, not `TO_CHAR`.  `TO_CHAR` converts a date into a string, but you want to do the exact opposite of this.

Second, if you want to use 24 hour time, you need to explicitly tell Oracle this by passing in a format string.  Try the following query:

```
UPDATE table1
SET dt_modified = TO_TIMESTAMP('01Feb2016 20:04:08.000', 'ddmonyyyy hh24:mi:ss.ff3')
WHERE dt_stamp = 'XXXXX' AND xcolumn = 'YYYY';
```

Comment: after your suggestion iam getting error as ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: @developer You should be using `TO_DATE` or `TO_TIMESTAMP`, _not_ `TO_CHAR`.